# Evaluate $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n+1}}{3^{2n}(2n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Evaluate $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n+1}}{3^{2n}(2n+1)!}$

For this homework problem, I really don't have any clue how to start it, so any hints are welcome. But my first intuition would be to determine its convergence using the ratio test.

But even if I did determine that it was convergent by RT, I'm not aware of how to evaluate it for the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the Taylor series of the sine function centered at $0$?

Comment: Well, the Taylor series of sin x is $\sum_{0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$. So the x value is then replaced by $\pi$, so its $\sum_{0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.

Comment: Why do you take $x=\pi$? Take $x=\frac\pi3$ instead.

Comment: So then, there is just the $\frac{1}{3^{2n}}$ portion, and then I evaluate that at 0? So would it be $\frac{1}{3^{2n}}*sin(x)$ at a = 0 --> $\frac{1}{3}*0$?

Comment: Oh, I see how $x = \frac{\pi}{3}$. So then would because the Maclaurin series converges to $\frac{1}{1^{2n}}sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$

Comment: Note that your series is equal to $3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\left(\frac\pi3\right)^n}{(2n+1)!}$. So, the sum is $3\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)=\frac{3\sqrt3}2$.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I think I get as you simplify the series and then replace it with what it converges to as Maclaurin series of sin x, cos x, and e^x all converge to those values, right?

Comment: Yes, that's it! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n+1}}{3^{2n}}=-3i\left(\dfrac{i\pi}3\right)^{2n+1}$$

So, the required sum $$S=-3i\dfrac{e^{i\pi/3}-e^{-i\pi/3}}2$$

using 
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Series_Expansion_for_Exponential_Function

$$\implies S=-3i\cdot i\sin\dfrac\pi3$$

Answer (score 0):

If you write down a few terms you will see that your series is indeed the Taylor series of $3\sin x$ evaluated at $x=\pi/3$

Thus the answer is $3\sin(\pi/3)$