# Find the Sum of the Series: $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n}}{6^{2n}(2n)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

Find the Sum of the Series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n}}{6^{2n}(2n)!}$$

Alright, so I think I may have gotten this problem correct but I'm a little hesitant, so If you could check my work/find where I went wrong that would be wonderful.

(1) It's a $cos x$ series, so I would simplify the series:
$$\frac{\pi}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\pi^n}{2n!}$$
(2) Which then I replace the sum of the series by the $cosx$ value:
$$\frac{\pi}{6}\cos{\pi}$$
(3) Then I evaluate:
$$\frac{\pi}{6}*(-1) = -\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Is this right?

Comment: You're expression in (1) is wrong - how did you remove $6^{2n}?$ The correct answer is to write out the series for $\cos x$ and then figure out what $x$ is. It is not $\pi.$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187624/evaluate-sum-0-infty-frac-1n-pi2n132n2n1/3187683#3187683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to construct the series from the original function explicitly
$$
\cos u = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n u^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
In your case, you need to make $u^{2n}$ look like $\pi^{2n}/6^{2n} = (\pi/6)^{2n}$ so we set $u = \pi/6$ and the LHS becomes
$$
\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for your input!